# Send curl request via https proxy

Tags: php

I need to send requests from my PHP code through https proxy.
I already tried, anyway I can think about with the PHP CURL, http_request2, file_get_content, but without any luck.

I actually need to translate the curl command:
`curl -x https://127.0.0.1:8089 https://api.ipify.org?format=json`
*must be https proxy*
To PHP way (without the exec, system, etc...)
Any ideas?

Comment: did you try CURLOPT_PROXY = https ://127.0.0.1:8089 + CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL = TRUE

Comment: Yes. No luck...

Comment: `CURLPROXY_HTTPS` is 7.52+ only. https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use curl with proxies with no problems at all.

There is some configuration options that you can use to achieve what you want. One of them is CURLOPT_PROXY
You can checkout all options to configure the proxy here: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: Php curl can't handle https proxy, only http proxy

Answer (score -1):

I found this useful function that does not check the SSL certificate:

```
/**
 * Get a web file (HTML, XHTML, XML, image, etc.) from a URL.  Return an
 * array containing the HTTP server response header fields and content.
 */
function get_web_page( $url )
{
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "spider", // who am i
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false     // Disabled SSL Cert checks
    );

    $ch      = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
    $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
    $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

    $header['errno']   = $err;
    $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
    $header['content'] = $content;
    return $header;
}
```

Comment: You don't use proxy in your script... I must go through my proxy